# Is this a workable chronology of the UX process?

Tags: process, chronology

Is this order of the UX process right?

1. Discover the user's problem
2. Create screener questionnaire
3. Call the users for their interview
4. Create a qualitative and quantitative questionnaire for the selected candidates that includes need based, task based, and value based questions
5. Support the primary research acquired from interviews with additional secondary research
6. Draw empathy maps (says, does, thinks, and feels)
7. User segmentation
8. Create abstraction results from your findings
9. User persona creation
10. User scenario
11. Storyboarding
12. Customer journey mapping
13. Task flow analysis
14. Information architecture
15. Wireframing and prototyping
16. Visual design
17. Usability testing

Comment: It's not wrong for some cases. But all cases are different. On top of it, this would be a flow that applies only to a process that leads to a web or mobile UI as deliverable, not a UX process that you can apply to any type of project

Answer (score 4):

The details of every UX Process looks different, depending on the timeframe, project-size and the topic. The base of the process will remain the same though. The parts you are described can be correct for a specific project. However, they won't work for every project. You can switch out certain methods and steps.

One base process that is often used in UX and helpfull to guide a rough path through the project, is the human-centered-design process. This process just defines four main steps.

**1. Understand and specify the context of use.**

**2. Specify the user requirements.**

**3. Produce design solution based on steps 1&2**

**4. Evaluate Design against requirements.**

Steps 1-4 will iterate as long as it needs to design a product that meet the user needs.

As you can see, the process is kept rough.
Based on the project you can now fill in the methods you would like to use.

For step 1 you could research the topic and the field as well, as the user. It is crucial that you get to know your user. In the best case you are talking to real users. You could use methods like Diary studies, Interviews, focus groups and surveys. It often helps to evaluate the different methods, before doing the next one. With the gained knowledge you will be able to ask more in depth questions.

In step 2, you would focus on the user needs. You will gather keypoints and knowledge you have gained in step 1. With methods like the question 0, you can gather the most important answers. The "How might we" Question helps to direct a direction of what kind of product will be needed and what points it has to fullfill, in order to be usefull for the user and the case.

In step 3 you will start a first "minimal viable prototype". Meaning, you would make a prototype that is only as defined, as it needs to be, in order to test the important features and userneeds. For this protoype you could make some sketches and wireframes. Depending on the project and the userneeds, you might be able to use wireframes for testing features.

In step 4 you will validate your project through users. You could use your prototype for A/B tests, or you could do an interview with a user and ask how they feel about certain design choices. You will gather all the keypoints the user can give you and improve the prototype.

Depending on the input of the user, you might have to go back to step one and do more research. Or you have to tweak something at step two and your user requirements. And then you have to adapt the prototype and go back to the user and test whether it is working better for them.

*The process you presented is not wrong. The question is just, is it right for the case/project?*